# border-radius in IE not working even though i'm using the .htc file

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I've been browsing around the web and i've found a few things that suggest that you can use a file called bprder-radius.htc to make the border radius attribute work in IE.

I've added the bit of code it suggest but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my source code

```
<div class="body">

<div class="menu">

    <p><a class="menuButton">Home</a></p>

    <p><a class="menuButton">Availability</a></p>

    <p><a class="menuButton">Treatments</a></p>

</div>

</div>
```

And my CSS

```
    .body {margin:auto; width:1096px; height:500px;}

.menu {position:relative; top:150px; overflow:hidden; -moz-opacity:.70; filter:alpha(opacity=70); opacity:.70; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -khtml-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; behavior: url(border-radius.htc);}

.menu p {text-align:center; width:124px; float:left; border:solid 1px #e94f7b; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -khtml-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px;}
```

Here's what I get in IE with this code

[image: Image1]

And here's what it should be

[image: Image2]

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Link to page - http://jamietaylor-webdesign.com/cms/

Comment: Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: Just uploading in to remote site will post a link shortly

Comment: @thirtydot please see link to page posted above - Thanks

Comment: It's not simple to make this work properly. You should switch to [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), but it will still be difficult to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [compass](http://compass-style.org/) which builds off of [sass](http://sass-lang.com). One of the interesting [compass integrations](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/pie/) is with [PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

PIE looks similar to IE-CSS3 http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ which was previously mentioned.

Comment: I ended up using PIE with the .js file rather than the HTC file and it works great - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the htc file needs to have a mimitype of text/x-comopnent

Method I use to do this is place the .htc files in a directory that has an *.htaccess* file with the following command.

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

If you have this in your .htaccess file then the .htc may have become corrupted by a FTP binary vs text upload / download between a uniq and windows based web host.

Get a new copy - try it on your local computer first - upload it with the .htaccess

IE-CSS3 http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ gives you more features than just corners.

border-radius
box-shadow
text-shadow

Comment: I've added this but it doesn't seem to work? I also added the ie-css3 htc file but I get and error - access denied on the file

Comment: used http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php for http://jamietaylor-webdesign.com/cms/border-radius.htc it is Content-Type: text/x-component

Comment: I would try adding it to a style tag in the html document ... IE may be ignoring it because it is chocking on one of the other commands in the css file.